# How to replace NA values between values based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, zoo

My zoo (time series) data set looks like below and goes on for hundreds of rows:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
NA NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA  3  3  3 NA NA  1  1

cycle4I <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1))
```

This variable is part of a larger zoo data set. The general pattern of this variable is a series of 1's, then NAs, then 3's, then NAs, and repeat the pattern again starting with a series of 1's. There is no regular pattern of the number of NAs.

I am trying to (i) fill the NAs between the 1's and 3's with 2, (ii) fill the NAs between the 3's and subsequent 1's with 4, and (iii) fill the NAs in the first four observations with 4 following the general pattern. When done, the values will be a series of 1, 2, 3, and 4 without a pattern of the quantity for each of the four values.

I have spent hours trying `ifelse` and `for` loops without success. (Relatively newbie with this part of R.)

I previous did this task in Stata but can't figure out the code in R to fill the NAs. The Stata code to fill the NAs is:

```
replace cycle4I = 2 if missing(cycle4I) & (cycle4I[_n-1] == 1 | cycle4I[_n-1] == 2) & (cycle4I[_n+1] == . | cycle4I[_n+1] == 3)

replace cycle4I = 4 if missing(cycle4I) & (cycle4I[_n-1] == 3 | cycle4I[_n-1] == 4) & (cycle4I[_n+1] == . | cycle4I[_n+1] == 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward way:

```
library(zoo)
cycle4I <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1))

x <- cycle4I

x[1] <- 3
x <- is.na(x) + na.locf(x)
x[1] <- 4
```

Which gives:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
 4  4  4  4  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  1  1
```

Comment: Very elegant. Learned from this. Didn't realize that a logical TRUE has a numerical value of 1: TRUE==1 produces TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

data_frame(cycle4I = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1)) %>%
  mutate(final = 
           cycle4I %>%
           lag %>%
           na.locf(na.rm = FALSE) %>%
           `+`(1) %>%
           ifelse(is.na(cycle4I),
                  ., cycle4I) )
```

Comment: Many thanks @bramtayl. I need to keep my larger data set as zoo class for zoo's time series features. I think this data_frame function makes this data as data.frame class although I guess one could cbind the above vector into the other zoo data.